# The code only prints the first if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

```
name = input("What is your name?")
talent = input("What is your main talent? ")
dream = input("What is your dream? ")
height = input("What is your height?(short or tall) ")
gender = input("What is your gender? ")

if gender == "male":
    print("Its okay buddy. You can do it! You have an amazing talent of " +
          talent + " and your dream of " + dream + " is amazing! ")

elif height == "tall" or "Tall":
    print(name + " ,You are a tall " + gender + " with an amazing talent of " +
          talent + " and")
elif gender == "female":
    print("nice to meet you")
```

- what is the mistake in this code? everytime that I run this regardless of the gender or height it always prints the first print statement. Any ideas?

Comment: No…?! I'd expect this to always print the second one (height), *unless you enter "male" as gender.*

Comment: jus replace elif height == "tall" or "Tall":
 with elif height.lower() == "tall"

Comment: In elif height.lower() == "tall", It consider no-empty value and that's why always return true.